# Can't install or update any software

Tags: 14.04, package-management, updates, software-center, dependencies

I'm new to Linux and I was trying a few new things. I was having problem install stuffs on software center at first because if this error

```
Failed to fetch http://llvm.org/apt/precise/dists/llvm-toolchain-precise-3.6/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I tried to fix it and now I can't even install stuffs with apt-get any more and these errors show up.

You might want to run `apt-get -f install` to correct these:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat : Depends: graphicsmagick but it is not going to be installed

              skype:i386 : 
              Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-webkit:i386 (>= 4:4.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This happen when I'm trying to install `graphicsmagick` or anything else. And no, `apt-get -f install` produce the same errors.

Comment: I just tried it and it just give another bunch of new depends like the above

Comment: you normally don't need to do this by hand - apt takes care about that - if it doesn't it can't solve the problems - so the dependencies are not "resolvable" - that is sometimes happening when you plug incompatible sources into your package-tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have sources defined in you sources.list file that are not present anymore, cause your mentioned llvm repo gives a:

```
APT mirror was temporary switched off due to excess load. We are working on bringing it back. Stay tuned!
```

so you could wait or deactivate the ressource in `software-properties-gtk` and try the mentioned things again...

after changing the sources or commenting them out in /etc/sources/sources.list or the subdirectories
after that you make an

```
sudo apt-get update
```

if this runs cleanly you could fire an

```
sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

perhaps you are than good to go...

Comment: Ok so how do I change the sources because I don't know anything and I don't want to mess up and crash the system

Comment: well your wrote "i tried to fix it" - perhaps you allready broke it at that stage, but if you want to do that in the gui you could open the software-properties-gtk application and search for the corresponding entries and just uncheck them...

Comment: yeah I unchecked llvm-toolchain-precise-3.6 and it works

Answer (score 0):

So I uncheck the llvm-toolchain-precise-3.6 in software & updates then type in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and it solve the problem. Now I could install thing like normal.